# How can evaluate more than once data from a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (VisitingCount int, [Time] int )
DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME,@i int,@Time int
set @DateNow='00:00'  
set @i=1;  
while(@i<48)  
    begin  
        set @DateNow = DATEADD(minute, 30, @DateNow)
        set @Time = (datepart(hour,@DateNow)*60+datepart(minute,@DateNow))/30 
        insert into #Temp(VisitingCount,[Time]) values(0,@Time )
        set @i=@i+1
    end

select Sum(VisitingCount)as VisitingCount, [Time]
  from #Temp group by [Time]
Union All
  select count(page) as VisitingCount, 
  (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30 as [Time]
  from scr_SecuristLog
  where Date between '2009-05-04 10:30' and '2009-05-04 12:30'
  GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30--scr
  order by 2 asc
```

This query creates me this table but if you look below "22" is repeating two times. in this situation. i should drop 0 value. i need

VisitingCount ------------Time----------
repeating------------------repeating-----
repeating------------------repeating-----
repeating------------------repeating-----
 526-----------------------21----------
0--------------------------22----------
0--------------------------22----------
0--------------------------23----------
825------------------------23----------
repeating------------------repeating-----
repeating------------------repeating-----

#### i need this Table

VisitingCount ------------Time----------
repeating------------------repeating-----
repeating------------------repeating-----
repeating------------------repeating-----
 526-----------------------21----------
0--------------------------22----------
825------------------------23----------
repeating------------------repeating-----
repeating------------------repeating-----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one more nesting level:

```
select Sum(VisitingCount)as VisitingCount, [Time]
from (
  select Sum(VisitingCount)as VisitingCount, [Time]
    from #Temp group by [Time]
  Union All
    select count(page) as VisitingCount, 
    (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30 as [Time]
    from scr_SecuristLog
    where Date between '2009-05-04 10:30' and '2009-05-04 12:30'
    GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30--scr
  ) X
group by [Time]
order by 2 asc
```

Comment: You are ok . But i need your hep an advanced query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852577/how-can-i-evaluate-this-table