# How can i evaluate this table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i need second table.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (VisitingCount int, [Time] int, [Date] nvarchar(50) )
DECLARE @DateNow DATETIME,@i int,@Time int, @Date nvarchar(50)
set @DateNow='00:00'  
set @i=1;  
while(@i<48)  
    begin  
        set @DateNow = DATEADD(minute, 30, @DateNow)
        set @Time = (datepart(hour,@DateNow)*60+datepart(minute,@DateNow))/30 
        set @Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),@DateNow, 108)
        insert into #Temp(VisitingCount,[Time],[Date]) values(0,@Time,@Date )
        set @i=@i+1
    end

select * from #Temp
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

select Sum(VisitingCount) as VisitingCount, Date
from (
  select Sum(VisitingCount) as VisitingCount, [Time],Date
    from #Temp group by [Time],Date
  Union All
    select count(page) as VisitingCount, 
    (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30 as [Time], CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108) as Date
    from scr_SecuristLog
    where Date between '2009-05-12' and '2009-05-13'
    GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/30,CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),Date, 108)
  ) X
group by Date
order by 2 asc
```

`VCount  Date

0       10:00

0       10:30

0   11:00

0   11:30

1   11:36

1   11:53

0   12:00

1   12:04

1   12:07

1   12:11

1   12:16

0   12:30

0   13:00

0   13:30

0   14:00

1   14:13

1   14:17

2   14:23

2   14:24

1   14:25`

---

i need this table look below please: Second Table

---

`VCount  Date

0   10:00

0   10:30

0   11:00

2   11:30

4   12:00

0   12:30

0   13:00

0   13:30

7   14:00`

Comment: Would you like to ask a question?

Comment: He wants to know how to change his SQL to sum over the half-hour periods

Comment: Dude, you've more patience than I

Comment: We all speak the universal language of code ; )

Answer (score 1):

here is some sample code that explains how you can use a CASE statement, you should be able to figure out how to make the changes in your code

```
--sample data
create table #temp (SomeDate datetime)
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 11:13:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 11:12:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 11:33:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 11:43:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 11:03:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 11:53:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 11:53:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 11:23:19.667')

insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 12:13:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 12:12:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 13:33:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 13:43:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 14:03:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 14:53:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 15:53:19.667')
insert #temp values ( '2009-05-12 15:23:19.667')



--this is the grouping/count query
select count(*),case when datepart(mi,Somedate) < 30 
then dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, Somedate)+0, 0)
 else dateadd(mi,30,dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, Somedate)+0, 0)) end
from #temp
group by case when datepart(mi,Somedate) < 30 
then dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, Somedate)+0, 0)
 else dateadd(mi,30,dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, Somedate)+0, 0)) end
```

to see what the data actually looks like

```
select Somedate,case when datepart(mi,Somedate) < 30 
then dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, Somedate)+0, 0)
 else dateadd(mi,30,dateadd(hh, datediff(hh, 0, Somedate)+0, 0)) end
from #temp
```

output

```
vCount  time
4   2009-05-12 11:00:00.000
4   2009-05-12 11:30:00.000
2   2009-05-12 12:00:00.000
2   2009-05-12 13:30:00.000
1   2009-05-12 14:00:00.000
1   2009-05-12 14:30:00.000
1   2009-05-12 15:00:00.000
1   2009-05-12 15:30:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

create a second table and use this to insert into it

```
select left(Date,2)+':00' as Date, sum(VCount) as VCount
from Table1
group by left(Date,2)
```